# Python 3 - Ideas for tasks involving .txt files

Tags: python, text

I have a project about text files I‘m working on. We have several different exercises to complete. However, one we have to create ourselves. I‘m kinda stuck since I don‘t really have any ideas on what do really do.

What are some interesting tasks we could do? (The txt file is around 10‘000 lines long)

We already have tasks to: split words and order them by length, amount of occurences for each word, input a word and then output all the sentences they occur in. And also some plotting of most used words. Is there an interesting task that is suitable for beginners?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

An easy one could be:

- Ask as input at least 3 separate char and find out all the words which contain those letters

A difficult one could be:

- Find out the longest character sequence (so even more than one word) which appears more than once in the text (maybe at least 3 times?)